# windows boot usb problem 13.04

Tags: usb, windows-7, live-usb, 13.04, startup-disk-creator

[image: Flashing error code I can't read]

I seem to be having trouble with 'start up disk creator'

The attached image shows a message that flashes off and on and off in rapid succession that I cant read. I seems to say I have a partition error so I changed the partition through 'G-parted' and formatted the stick (to ntfs) for a windows boot but it let me create a windows boot stick from an iso or disk image. I have used a couple of other programs and the problem just re-occurs everytime, some let me let 50% done then it crashes. I need windows because wine is just silly some times and I want to play GTA3 (old I know but still the best game ever) 
but use Ubuntu for EVERYTHING else. I am running 13.04 and wonder what I can do to remedy the problem.

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to make a bootable windows installer. There is a great program out there that I have used in the past called WinUSB. This program allows you to make a bootable windows installer, just like you can with LiveLinuxUSB Creator and such, but with Windows. To install, open Terminal and do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get winusb
```

To actually create the drive, open WinUSB, select your .iso/cd-drive, select your usb flash drive/hard drive at the bottom, and click begin.

Comment: Looks good this mate. It wouldn't let me download it from the com line but once I found it I downloaded the .deb package and its copying the data as we speak...... type.  Thanks

Comment: This worked perfectly and even though I messed up a triple boot a couple of time thanks to ubuntu and YOU I can now boot whatever of the 4 operating systems I want. Thanks a lot man